# Get objects with a list in JPA native query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a native query that return list of objects, and inside every object an attribute of type list :

Child interface :

```java
public interface ChildInterface {
    public Integer getId();
    public String getCode();
    public String getLabel();
}
```

Example interface :

```java
public interface ExampleInterface {
    public Integer getId();
    public String getLabel();
    public List<ChildInterface> getChildren();
}
```

I need to create a **native query** to get **Example** list with there **Children** :

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select e.id as id from example e .....")
List<ExampleInterface> search()
```

---

Tables:

> Example: id, label

> Child: id, code, label, example_id

Comment: If you must use a native query, then you will have to select `List<Object[]>` and transform the results to your custom objects. Why do you have to use a native query?